# m2eclipse problem with artifact resolution - suggest another maven plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

With recent version of m2eclipse (0.12.1.20110112-1712) I am facing really weird problems with artifact resolutions. the project is building just fine with command-line. The artifacts do really exist in local maven repository.

I tried to

- enable/disable dependency management
- update project configuration
- update dependencies
- not using embedded maven 3.0 but use external maven 2.2.1
- use different JDK in eclipse.ini
- voodoo magic

but nothing helps.

Please suggest what else may I try or some replacement for this plugin.

Comment: weird, voodoo magic usually helps with m2eclipse ;-)

Comment: NetBeans 7 usually does the trick. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could uninstall m2eclipse and use the eclipse:eclipse plugin for maven instead.  This will generate/update your .project and .classpath files for you.  Then, when your pom changes, you just run mvn eclipse:eclipse again to update them.

Comment: I would prefer that option but how to easily manage tons of dependencies ?

Comment: mvn eclipse:eclipse takes care of updating the dependencies in your project, so managing tons shouldn't be any different than managing a few.

Comment: I was a bit stuck in the head ;) used eclipse:eclipse and imported as maven project...then at the 3th try I imported as general java project as it should be...and it works now..I just got one problem...I have a servlet.jar with scope: provided that its only in the project-classpath but not in the war..despite of that its packed in the war-file (web-inf/lib)...Do I have to use another scope?

Comment: "provided" is the correct scope for that and maven should exclude it from the war.  I'm not sure how eclipse will handle it (if you are using eclipse to build the war).

Comment: I'm using maven 2.2.1 from cmd..because I had too much trouble with the eclipse maven plugin..I wonder why maven is doing this..hmm..

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click and update the Maven Configuration, the dependency should appear in Maven Dependencies folder under the project.

You could try closing and reopening the project. Don't laugh - this recently worked for a coworker of mine using m2eclipse.

Otherwise, there is an option somewhere about detecting Maven dependencies embodied by other projects within the same Eclipse workspace. Maybe in the build settings for the project?

Beware the voodoo magic.